# Eclipse debugger C++ 'No source available for "std::ostream::operator<<()"'; 'std::endl' issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I am debugging a program that I have built. The program compiles and runs without error.

When using the debugger gcc4.9.3 (rtools_34) I get a message:

'No source available for "std::ostream::operator<<()"'

When stepping over any lines that contain std::cout << "Text" << std::endl;
This causes the debugging to crash. However if I set a breakpoint past the rogue code I can skip it without problem.

The code includes: iostream, ostream and string.

This code has also been debugged with other compilers without this issue. It is a new import into Eclipse for a newer compiler so I am assuming that I have set things up wrong.

The problem appears to be with std::endl as using '\n' instead works.

Any hints on interpretation of the error message or how to resolve the problem greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you replace `"Text"` with a `std::string`?  It seems like the compiler is unable to convert the literal into a type that is `<<`-able.   Replacing the literal with an explicit instance of a `std::string` might give you another clue.

Comment: Do you mean to include:

std::string test = "Text";
std::cout << test << std::endl;

if so then the error is the same.

Comment: I have encounter the same issue. did you manage to fix it?
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020983/eclipse-debugger-c-no-source-available-for-stdostreamoperator

Comment: No solution so far. I was using breakpoints to bypass the problem. Let me know if you find a solution. I'm currently working on something else but will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to 
`#include <string>`?

Sorry if that was obvious and has been checked, it just wasn't clear that that was definitely the case from your question!

Comment: No problem Fred. Yes the code does contain #include <string>

Comment: Another little thing to check (unlikely to fix but may narrow things down again) might be to explicitly use \n - as in 
std::cout << "Text\n" 
- endl should be included in iostream, but this checks just in case (it isn't explicitly required to prior to C++11)

Comment: The last thing I can think of is that the debug flags for your compiler haven't been set. I realise all three of my suggestions are simple ones that I expect you would have checked already before coming on here, but I hope they do no harm as reminders in case? Hopefully someone else will come along and solve this assuming that it's none of these!

Comment: I do have the debug flags set yes, should have said. I have tried with '-g' and with '-g3'.

However using std::cout << "Text\n" works when std::endl doesn't. What are the implications of that? My compiler is gcc4.9.3 which is post C++11.

Comment: C++11 isn't always used unless specified explicitly in the flags, so maybe adding <ostream> explicitly and/or using -std=c++11 as a flag (or -std=c++0x) may help identify if that's the problem? (At least it's narrowed it down to being something about std::endl!)

Comment: Explicitly adding <ostream> doesn't have any effect.

Currently I can't compile using the -std=c++0x flag. The code is large and legacy, originally developed by another organisation.

Comment: In which case I'm afraid I can't think of or find any fix from there! I hope your updated question brings in someone else who may be able to think of further fixes. Hopefully until then the `<< "\n"` (or maybe `<< "\n" << std::flush`) alternatives can be a workaround!