# eclipse debugger c++ - No source available for "std::ostream::operator<<

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to run a simple program and use the eclipse dubgger but I keep receivng the following error:
   No source available for "std::ostream::operator<<
The code:

```
int main()
{
  int num1(0);
  int num2 = 0;

  std::cout << "Please enter the first number:" << std::endl ;
  std::cin >> num1;

  std::cout << "Please enter the second number:" << std::endl ;
  std::cin >> num2;
}
```

BTW by trying to debug a simple 'hello world' ptogram I received the following error:
Can't find a source file at "C:\Users\DB\workspace\Temp\src\Temp.cpp" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

I am using MinGW gcc compailer. I attached print screens for the configuratuon of the debugger.

[debug configuratuion 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmdpM.jpg)

[debug configuratuion 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCaoG.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to step into the `operator<<` overloads? Why? Step *over* them instead.

Comment: I am trying to step over...